How can I use a variable declared in a .then of a function
I declared a variable in the .then of a function calling an api and I was wondering how to make it global.
I tried this:

    var apiResponse;
     function run(){
         var input = document.getElementById("serchbar").value; 
         var firs = input.split(' ')[0]; 
         var seco = input.split(' ')[1]; 
         console.log(firs); 
         console.log(seco); 
         fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=${firs}%2C%20${seco}&key=91c2039590b440a28b8203430240503`) 
            .then(response => response.json()) 
            .then(data => { var apiResponse = (data); 
                console.log(apiResponse.current.temp_c); }) 
            .catch(error => console.error(error)); 
         console.log(apiResponse)
    }

But,when I console logged outside of the .then, I got an undefined

It's not a problem with the scope. It's a problem with the timing.var apiResponse = (data) happens after console.log(apiResponse).

See also Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference

the problem can (and probably should ) be solved by awaiting the result of fetch. This can be done only from within an async function or a module.
